# Next.js: Create products with Shopify product api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, shopify-app, shopify-api

I am working on an embedded shopify application and i have a task where i need to get all products from a third party api and import them into shopify store's product page. I am trying to make a request to shopify product api through the server. But, i am not successful.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
router.post("/api/importproducts", koaBody(), async (ctx) => {
    const {shop} = await getShop(ctx);
    try {
      const accessToken = await performQuery(
        `SELECT accesstoken FROM userspecificdata WHERE shopdomain = '${shop}'`
      );
      const data = JSON.parse(ctx.request.body);
      fetch(`https://${shop}/admin/api/2021-04/products.json`, {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "Authorization":`${accessToken[0].accesstoken.trim()}`, 
          'X-Shopify-Access-Token': process.env.SHOPIFY_API_SECRET,
        }
      })
      .then((response) => console.log(response))
      ctx.body = { status: "success" };
    }catch (err) {
      ctx.body = { status: "error" };
    }
  })
```

The response that i am getting is below

```
Response {
┃   size: 0,
┃   timeout: 0,
┃   [Symbol(Body internals)]: {
┃     body: PassThrough {
┃       _readableState: [ReadableState],
┃       _events: [Object: null prototype],
┃       _eventsCount: 5,
┃       _maxListeners: undefined,
┃       _writableState: [WritableState],
┃       allowHalfOpen: true,
┃       [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
┃       [Symbol(kTransformState)]: [Object]
┃     },
┃     disturbed: false,
┃     error: null
┃   },
┃   [Symbol(Response internals)]: {
┃     url: 'https://lostorex2.myshopify.com/admin/api/2021-04/products.json',
┃     status: 400,
┃     statusText: 'Bad Request',
┃     headers: Headers { [Symbol(map)]: [Object: null prototype] },
┃     counter: 0
┃   }
┃ }
```

and the data that i am sending with the body of POST request is below.

```
 {
┃   product: {
┃     title: 'Tomy Aquadoodle Classic - Pink',
┃     body_html: 'The Classic Pink Aquadoodle brings different shades of your favourite colour to life for hours of magical drawing fun and creativity without any mess. Simply fill the pen with water, run the nib over the magic mat and see the colours appear. As the drawing dries the design fades away making the mat ready to be used all over again. This Classic Aquadoodle Mat puts you in the pink for hours of magical mess-free drawing fun.',
┃     price: '£20.00',
┃     images: [ [Object] ]
┃   }
┃ }
```

My initial guess was that the api url i am making a request to was wrong, but, i am not sure and i cannot find any concrete example of how to make a post request with shopify product url.

Comment: Try off docs examples first 
https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/products/product#create-2021-04

Comment: @NikitaMazur, I have tried it already. But, it does not work. It is weird. when i try the get request to get products from shopify products, it gives me the products but for post, it gives me the error. Now it is giving authorization error but, i checked my access token, it is correct.

Comment: Are you sure that you have the necessary rights to make posts requests?

Comment: @Gh05d. Yes, i do have specific rights and i fixed the problem, the problem was that the access token that i had was old one and needed to be updated. I uninstall and reinstalled the application and updated the access token in my database and it worked.